# Access UITextFields text from custom cells class to the main VCs class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom cell that I created in the storyboard which is linked to a class called `customCell`. In it, I have `UITextFields` that are linked to `customCell.h`. The `textField` do have different tags for them.

Then there is a class called `mainVC`. That class is the class of the `viewController`

How can I get the `textFields` text in the `mainVC` class?

The easiest, but **wrong** way of doing it is like so:

```
CustomCell *myCell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
```

The problem of doing this, is, it will create a *new* `customCell`, and therefore the `textFields` text will be a null.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `textFields` not `textView`

Answer (score 0):

You don't access the text field to get the text, you implement one of the UITextFieldDelegate (or UITextView, it's not clear which you have) methods in your view controller. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, set the controller (self) to be the delegate of the text field. You probably want to implement textFieldDidEndEditing: and 
textFieldShouldReturn:. After the keyboard is dismissed, textFieldDidEndEditing: will be called, and you can get the text inside that method. If you need to get the indexPath of the cell the text field was contained in, you can use the table view method, indexPathForRowAtPoint:, passing the text field's origin or center for the point argument.

Comment: the `textFieldDidEnd...` should be in the `mainVC`, not `customCell`, write?     Also, are you saying I should make an if statement for every textField, then assign the correct one to a string? Meaning if I want a textField called: `nameTextField`, I should create an if statement, checking if that was the textField the user entered text with, then assign that to a string: `nameString`.?

Comment: @MikeRally, yes, I did say that the delegate method should be in the controller. If you have multiple text field's per cell, then you do need if statements (or a switch statement) to distinguish among the text fields.

Comment: Do I have to set every textField as delegate in `celllForRow...`?

Comment: @MikeRally, yes, each textfield need to have its delegate set.

Comment: The problem is I have more than 1 cell ID, say the 1st textView in the first cell. So when `cellForRow...` goes through the first cell, it will set it correctly. But when `cellForRow...` goes to the second cell, it will set the 1st textViews delegate to self, but the textView will be null. Do you understand, or should I explain it better?